# SQL Connection with Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js, node-modules

I am getting error

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to GURPANTH:undefined in 15000ms.

The port for TCP/IP are enabled.

Here is a glimpse of my sql server settings.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at0Tx.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW3QK.png)

```
 var sql = require('mssql');
    var dbConfig = {
        server: 'GURPANTH\\MSSQLSERVER01',
        database:'Employee',
        user:'Gurpanth\Gurpanth',
        password:'',
        port: 1433
    };

    function getEmp() {
        var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
        conn.connect().then(function () {
            var req = new sql.Request(conn);
            req.query("Select * from employee").then(function () {
                console.log(recordSet);
                conn.close();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                conn.close();
            });

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    getEmp();
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP protocol is not enabled on your server. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb909712(v=vs.90).aspx